# Android Webview Copy,Search,Find not Working

Tags: android, android-webview, copy-paste

I am having an issue with `WebView` I have changed the contextual text selection menu of `WebView` to add some more functionality but the issue which arose due to that is that I lost all the default buttons of `WebView` which were

copy , select all , paste , share etc...

I want those buttons to be there and working plus display some extra buttons to achieve my custom functionality which is highlight and add notes etc.

Please let me know how to do this.

Here is my code for modifying the `WebView` and adding custom action bar instead of default `ActionBar`.

```
public class CustomWebView  extends WebView{
CustomizedSelectActionModeCallback actionModeCallback;
public Context context;
public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //      ViewParent parent = getParent();
   //        if (parent == null) {
     //            return null;
     //        }
    actionModeCallback = new CustomizedSelectActionModeCallback();
    return startActionModeForChild(this,actionModeCallback);

}

public class CustomizedSelectActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback{

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mode.setTitle("Select Action");

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_delete:
            clearFocus();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This is my test click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;


        case R.id.item_HighLight:
            ReaderActivity.btn_ColorChooser.performClick();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        clearFocus(); // this  is not clearing the text in my device having version 4.1.2
        actionModeCallback=null;

    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution which i found for this problem was BTSelectionWebView. This is a layer on top of webview which opens a popup menu just like you have in IOS when you select text and the menu appears on top showing options. it really worked like a charm for me

Here is the Link to GitHub Project.

https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are attempting is possible.

If you override `startActionMode` as you have done, you are discarding the system callback that instantiates the default options (copy, paste, search, etc) and replacing it entirely with your own actions. If you want the actions from the default, you will, unfortunately, have to implement them yourself.

Side note: In all my research and personal experience, I believe overriding `startActionMode` is the only way to implement a custom contextual action bar within a `WebView` while maintaining the selection functionality provided by the Android system. There are other ways to show the CAB, but they remove the selection functionality.

Comment: I did so, Rahter Did a better approach than this. now i have popup menu like IOS. in webview text selection.